# A generic error occurred in GDI+ + ABCPdf + Load Balancing

Tags: asp.net, load-balancing

We are using two load balancing server for asp.net site in that we have a functionality which will create a receipt of order in pdf using abcpdf component it was working fine without load balancing server and but when we move it to load balancing server it is giving errors like. A generic error occurred in GDI. I have given full rights to directory which is used but still there problem. Does anybody have a solutions for this.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve these errors? We're experiencing similar issues on a load balanced server.

Comment: We have resolved it via giving proper rights to the folder where you are creating Images which you are incorporate in the PDF. The rights should be same as your application pool identity.

Comment: Thanks very much for your response, we'll give that a try.

Comment: Out of interest, how did you diagnose this issue, because as far as we can see there's no logging output by ABCPDF to indicate the underlying error?

Comment: We just do trial and Error and found that.. Nothing else..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot believe that. It fixed it. The other server had the permission, but the server that was throwing an error message did not have correct permission. We copied missing user permission from the sane server folder to insane server folder.